# get the inner value of list item when clicked through javascript

Tags: javascript, list, innerhtml

I have a users list, I am retrieving all users from database and listing them as below

```
<div class="online-users">
    <ul id="outer-list">
        @foreach($users->getUsers() as $user)
            {{--remove white spaces from name--}}
            <?php $name = str_replace(' ','-',$user->name);?>

                <li onclick="openMessageBox()" id="user" class="inner-list-item">{{$user->name}}</li><br>

        @endforeach
    </ul>
</div>
```

This is what I want to achieve when we click on any list item, I want to grab that user's name. But what I have tried so far is

```
<script>
    function openMessageBox(){
        var user_id = document.getElementById('outer-list');
        user_id=user_id.getElementsByClassName('inner-list-item').innerHTML;
        window.alert(user_id);
        document.getElementById('message-box').style.display="block";

    }
</script>
```

it only gives me access to the user's name if I use [index] with

```
user_id=user_id.getElementsByClassName('inner-list-item')[5].innerHTML;
```

I do not want to explicitly tell the index every time. Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Have you considered using data attributes for this? Such as `<li data-username="Foo"...` in case you want to include more than just the username at a later date.

Comment: Don't quote PHP code for JavaScript questions. Quote the HTML that it generates.

Comment: @rybo111 thanks man, this is what I may need soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass in the element reference to the function:

```
<li onclick="openMessageBox(this)" id="user" class="inner-list-item">{{$user->name}}</li><br>
```

and then get the username by simply reading the element's `textContent` (this will work for attributes as well, as @rybo111 suggested in the comments):

```
function openMessageBox(el){
    var name = el.textContent;
}
```

---

Simple live example:

```js
function openMessageBox(el){
  var name = el.textContent;
  alert(name);
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li onclick="openMessageBox(this)">Alice</li>
  <li onclick="openMessageBox(this)">Bob</li>
</ul>
```

---

And btw. you'll end up having duplicate `user` IDs on those li elements.

Comment: duplicate `user` IDs how?

Comment: In your foreach you render li elements and each of them will have the `id="user"` part. IDs should be unique, use `class` instead or append the actual user id to the ID string.

Comment: how to append actual user id to string? this is how I can get user_id `$user->id`

Comment: I'd still go with `class="user"`, but if you want to append, you can insert PHP there: `id="user_<?php echo $user->id; ?>"` or just `id="user_<?= $user->id ?>"`

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass current ref as a parameter.

```
<input id="theId" value="test" onclick="doSomething(this)" />

// Javascript
function(elem){
    var value = elem.value;
    var id    = elem.id;
    ...
}
```

Comment: Where did you get the input element? What question are you answering?

Comment: By referring above example its not difficult to find the solution of your issue. You just need to use the logic.

Comment: I have no trouble solving the issue, but pasting a random code snippet from somewhere (or even purposely writing a wrong example) doesn't add much value to SO.